# any plugin where user modify their profile and post panel at front end?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I want to know is there any plugin(s) where user first registered as editor then create a post or modify own post.

users can manage their profile and post panel.

I have searched a lots of plugins but still not found any sufficient.

i am newbee in wordpress. and little bit knowledge about wordpress. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I exactly dont know what you want to do .but from the statement "where user first registered as editor then create a post or modify own post." i believe you want to have a form where user first registers and then assign riles according to that..if this is the case then you can easily define ROLES to users and grant privileges from admin back end..let me know the clear cut case

Comment: @swapnesh sir, i want to create a portal site where user first register at front end, can manage their profile, after that can create  posts of related category and manage their post.

Comment: for best example of my query is :
articlebase.com
i just want to create a clone of that site.

Comment: check this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/  OR search repository with keywords like user roles/registration etc http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial [HERE](http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/).
Works for me. It's not so super-easy, but if you want to create clone of that side- you need to understand it.